# Optimal Algorithm needed for finding pairs divisible by a given integer k

Tags: algorithm

Given n integers and an integer k, tell how many such pairs of the given n integers exist such that the sum of the two elements in the pair is divisible by k ?

I don't know the bounds on n and k. So, for the sake of simplicity, assume n and k are not very large.

It goes without saying, give as optimal solution as possible. ( I know the naive method :-) ! )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whether the sum of two numbers is divisible by `k` only depends on their remainders modulo `k`.

So if `k` is reasonably small, you can just count how many numbers have each possible remainder and compute the number of pairs from that. Assuming `k > 0` and all integers nonnegative

```
unsigned long long combinations(unsigned k, unsigned long long *arr, unsigned n) {
    unsigned long long counts[k] = {0};
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ++counts[arr[i]%k];
    }
    // number of pairs where both are divisible by k
    unsigned long long combs = counts[0]*(counts[0]-1)/2;
    for(i = 1; i < (k+1)/2; ++i) {
        combs += counts[i]*counts[k-i];
    }
    if (k == 2*i) {
        combs += counts[i]*(counts[i] - 1)/2;
    }
    return combs;
}
```

does the job in `O(n+k)` steps. If `n` is small and `k` very large, the naive algorithm is better.

Comment: You beat me to it :) However, you want to use counts[], not arr[] where you're doing the combs, and you need to consider counts[0]

Comment: Great ! Linear time.. that's what I was looking for.. Thanks !

Comment: @rici Thanks for the heads-up. `counts[0]` is used in the initialisation of `combs`, I didn't forget that (but I had another typo, `k-1` instead of `k-i`).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Daniel Fischer says, if k is very large, you can sort the numbers mod k, and then walk the sorted list from both ends (after dealing with the 0 mod k values) towards the middle (k/2 mod k). That's O(n log n), which is better then O(n^2), assuming that your naive algorithm is really naive.

Comment: My Naive involved Binary Search... So that would also be O(n log n) but yes, your version is an improvement... since it only involves O(n log n) for sorting.. and does finding in linear O(n) time rather than O(n log n) using Binary Search. Thanks ! +1 :)

Comment: You could use a hashtable instead of sorting/binary search to get down to O(n).

Comment: @KeithRandall, yes, you could try that. I'd expect that my solution would usually be faster, because its inner loop is very fast, but I could well be wrong. If you want to try it, I'd suggest a good hash for an integer mod k would be the integer mod k mod p where p is a prime close to n. That keeps the storage to O(n), which is competitive with search-and-scan. (Using the integer mod k itself would of course guarantee no collisions, but then you've reduced the problem to Daniel's binsort, and we've discarded that in this case because the bins take up too much memory.)