# Better algorithm (than using a dict) for enumerating pairs with a given sum.

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a number, I have to find out all possible index-pairs in a given array whose sum equals that number. I am currently using the following algo:

```
def myfunc(array,num):
    dic = {}
    for x in xrange(len(array)):  # if 6 is the current key,
        if dic.has_key(num-array[x]):  #look at whether num-x is there in dic
            for y in dic[num-array[x]]: #if yes, print all key-pair values
                print (x,y),
        if dic.has_key(array[x]):  #check whether the current keyed value exists
            dic[array[x]].append(x)  #if so, append the index to the list of indexes for that keyed value
        else:
            dic[array[x]] = [x]  #else create a new array
```

Will this run in `O(N)` time? If not, then what should be done to make it so? And in any case, will it be possible to make it run in `O(N)` time without using any auxiliary data structure?

Comment: What do you mean by off-topic? When you ask for solution wthout providing code, you are penalised for not showing your research. When you do, you say it should be migrated?

Comment: @vascowhite (and other close voters): Which part of the FAQ specifically do you think it "violates"? From the FAQ: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face`. He is giving a problem and his attempt on it. He also asks for a specific scoped question (what is the complexity? Can it be done better then O(n)?)

Comment: Correct me if I didn't got your question but if you want to find all pairs whose sum is equal to a given number than those pair individually have to be less than that number. So, lets suppose if you are given a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and you have to find all pairs having `sum==6` than you can first filter out the list to `[1,2,3,4,5,6] and than find those pairs.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too. But that won't help the efficiency much, will it?

Comment: Not for small list but when I increased the size to `range(300000)`. your solution took `~3secs` whereas mine with the above logic took `0.7secs`. So, my logic will not change the complexity but will definetely improve the run time.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Sometimes two solutions with similar complexities can give different results. Thanks.

Comment: @Noob: This optimization works only if all elements in the array are *positive*.

Comment: Yeah yeah, right! Didn't think of it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will this run in O(N) time?

Yes and no. The complexity is actually `O(N + M)` where `M` is the *output size*.

Unfortunately, the output size is in `O(N^2)` worst case, for example the array `[3,3,3,3,3,...,3]` and `number == 6` - it will result in quadric number of elements needed to be produced.

However - asymptotically speaking - it cannot be done better then this, because it is linear in the input size and output size.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? It isn't entirely clear to me. There is a similar solution at http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/09/17/programming-interview-questions-1-array-pair-sum/, do you think it will perform better?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I don't think the linked solution is correct - as it does not handle duplicate elements - which seems to be a thing you want. The linked solution runs in `O(nlogn)` time and `O(1)` space - but as said, does not print all duplicate elements.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: It is `O(N logN)` and not `O(logN)` - due to the sorting: `arr.sort()` which is `O(N logN)`. It also does not print all dupes, like the example of 3's in my answer, so it is wrong unless you assume no dupe elements.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I might have misunderstood you in comments: The first solution in the link is indeed `O(NlogN)` as discussed. The second one (did not see it until now) is `O(N)` time & space, it is basically the same as yours - but it again fails for dupes, because it inserts elements to a set, so inserting 3 bunch of times will result in a `seen` set of size 1, and the result will be wrong. The conclusion remains - if you want to allow dupes, you cannot avoid the possible `O(N^2)` running time, because it is the size of your output. Hope it helps and clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 3):

Very, very simple solution that actually does run in O(N) time by using array references. If you want to enumerate all the output pairs, then of course (as amit notes) it must take O(N^2) in the worst case.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def findpairs(arr, target):
    flip = defaultdict(list)
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        flip[j].append(i)
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        if target-j in flip:
            yield i, flip[target-j]
```

Postprocessing to get all of the output values (and filter out `(i,i)` answers):

```
def allpairs(arr, target):
    for i, js in findpairs(arr, target):
        for j in js:
            if i < j: yield (i, j)
```

Comment: However this solution is rather Python-specific. I was thinking of a more portable solution.

Comment: It's not Python-specific. You could implement it in any other language with a hashtable of linked lists (hashtables for O(1) lookup, linked lists so that you can just reference the head for the desired indices).

Comment: offtop: to allow `arr` to be an arbitrary iterable: `for j in flip: if target-j in flip: yield flip[j], flip[target-j]` It yields list of `i`s with corresponding list of `j`s (to be unpacked in `allpairs()`)

Answer (score 1):

This might help - [Optimal Algorithm needed for finding pairs divisible by a given integer k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545544/optimal-algorithm-needed-for-finding-pairs-divisible-by-a-given-integer-k)

(With a slight modification, there we are seeing for all pairs divisible by given number and not necessarily just equal to given number)