# Find the number of pairs whose sum is divisible by k?

Tags: numbers, combinations, combinatorics

Given a value of k. Such that k<=100000
We have to print the number of pairs such that sum of elements of each pair is divisible by k.
under the following condition first element should be smaller than second, and both element should be less than 10<sup>9</sup>.

Comment: And what have you done so far for this assignment?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i used the brute force technique but failed

Comment: Can you post the code you tried so that we can help you figure out what went wrong with it?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545781/2636873) answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution, let `a` and `b` numbers such that `(a+b)%k=0` then we have to find that pairs `(a,b)`, where `a<b`, so let's count how many pairs `(a,b)` satisfy the condition that `a+b=k`, for example if `k=3` `0+3=3, 1+2=3, 2+1=3, 3+0=3` there are 4 pairs but only 2 pairs which is `(K+1)/2 (integer division)` so similar for find the pairs `(a,b)` which sum is `2k, 3k,.. nk`, and the solution will be `(k+1)/2 + (2k+1)/2 + (3k+1)/2 + ... + (nk+1)/2`, and that is equal to `(k*n*(n+1)/2 + n)/2` with time complexity `O(1)`, take care in the case if `n*k=2*10^9`, because `a` can't be more than `10^9` for the given constraint.

Comment: did not get this statement "only 2 pairs which is (k+1)/2" what does it mean

Comment: @user765443 as (0,3) is same as (3,0) and (1,2) is same as (2,1)

Answer (score 1):

Solution in O(N) time and O(N) space using hash map.

### The concept is as follows:

```
If (a+b)%k=0 where

a=k*SOME_CONSTANT_1+REMAINDER_1 

b=k*SOME_CONSTANT_2+REMAINDER_2

then (REMAINDER_1 +REMAINDER_2 )%k will surely be 0
```

so for an array (4,2,3,31,14,16,8) and k  =5 if you have some information like below , you can figure out which all pairs sum %k =0

[image]

Note that, Bottom most row consist of all the remainders from 0 to k-1  and all the numbers corresponding to it.
Now all you need to do is move both the pointer towards each other until they meet. If both the pointers locations have number associated with it their sum%k will be 0

To solve it, you can keep track of all the remainder you have seen so far by using hash table

1. create  a hash map Map<Integer, List>.
2. Pre-populate its keys with 0 to k-1;
3. iterate over array and put remainder of each number in the map with Key = remainder and put the actual  number in the list,
4. Iterate over the key set using two pointers moving each other. And `sum += listSizeAsPointedByPointer1 * listSizeAsPointedByPointer2`

Answer (score 0):

One way is brute force:

```
int numPairs = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10e9; i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < 10e9; j++)
    {
        int sum = i + j;
        if (sum % k == 0) numPairs++;
    }
 }
 return numPairs;
```

I'll leave it up to you to optimize this for performance.  I can think of at least one way to significantly speed this up.

Comment: this is brute force technique which i know. can you suggest other technique?

Comment: this code will take too much time, can you suggest optimised algorithm

Comment: First optimization: observe that many different pairs of numbers have the same sum (ex: 57 and 100, 58 and 99, 59 and 98, 60 and 97, etc).  You are wasting your time summing and modding the same value over and over again.  Here's a hint: how many sum values there are for two integers between 0 and 10e9? Answer: 2 x 10e9.  Your problem has been reduced from O(n^2) to O(n)!

Answer (score -1):

Some psuedo-code to get you started. It uses the brute-force technique you say you tried, but maybe something was wrong in your code?

```
max = 1000000000
numberPairs = 0
for i = 1 to max - 2 do
    for j = i + 1 to max - 1 do
        if (i + j) mod k = 0 then
            numberPairs = numberPairs + 1
        end if
    end do
end do
```

Comment: this code will take too much time, can you suggest optimised algorithm